# Minimum number of roots of a polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots, rolles-theorem

> For a polynomial () with real coefficients, let $_$ denote the number of distinct real roots of
> $()$. Suppose  is the set of polynomials with real coefficients defined by $ =\{{(^2 − 1)^2(_0 +_1+_2^2 + _3^3) ∶ _0, _1, _2, _3 ∈ ℝ}\}$.For a polynomial , let ′and ′′ denote its first and second order derivatives, respectively. Then the minimum possible value of $(_{′} + _{′′})$, where  ∈ , is _____

I know that roots cannot be solved individually but can be solved/found buy the application of Rolle's theorem. How do we find the minimum number of roots for the first and second derevative

Comment: No the official answer in the answer key is 5

Comment: $mf'$ will have minimum 3 roots and $mf''$ will have minimum 2 roots

Comment: Is there a problem in the notation? Is it supposed to be $m_f{'} + m_f{''}$?

Comment: This was asked in ADVANCED JEE PAPER-1 2020 held on 26 september

Comment: done the necessary modification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $S={(x-1)}^2{(x+1)}^2(p(x))$ we have $(1,-1)$ are repeated roots!:$f'(1)=f'(-1)=0$

$f(1)=f(-1)=0$ hence $f'(k)=0$ for some $k$ in $(-1,1)$.Also $f'(-1)=f'(1)=0$(repeated root).

$f'(-1)=f'(k)=0$ hence there is some $d$ in $(-1,k)$ $f''(d)=0$ similarly threre is some $m$ in $(k,1) $ for $f''(m)=0$.

thus minimum number of roots of $f'$ is $3$: roots are $(-1,1,k)$

and for $f''$ roots are :$(m,d)$

Thus a minimum value is 5